# What is the best way to call an authenticated HTTP Cloud Function from Node JS app deployed in GCP?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We have an authenticated HTTP cloud function (CF). The endpoint for this CF is public but because it is authenticated, it requires a valid identity token (`id_token`) to be added to the `Authorization` header.

We have another Node JS application that is deployed in the same Google Cloud. What we want is to call the CF from the Node application, for which we will be needing a valid id token.

The [GCP documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#application-default-credentials) for authentication is too generic and does not have anything for such kind of scenario.

*So what is the best way to achieve this?*

**Note** 
Like every google Kubernetes deployment, the node application has a service account attached to it which already has cloud function invoker access.

**Follow Up**
Before posting the question here I had already followed the same approach as [@guillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11372593/guillaume-blaquiere) mentioned in his answer.
In my current code, I am hitting the metadata server from the Node JS application to get an `id_token`, and then I am sending the `id_token` in a header `Authorization: 'Bearer [id_token]'` to the CF HTTP request.

However, I am getting a `403` `forbidden` when I do that. *I am not sure why??*
[image]

I can verify the `id_token` fetched from the metadata server with the following endpoint. 
[https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=[id_token]](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=%5Bid_token%5D)

It's a valid one.
And it has the following fields. 
Decoding the `id_token` in https://jwt.io/ shows the same field in the payload.

```
{
    "issued_to": "XXX",
    "audience": "[CLOUD_FUNTION_URL]",
    "user_id": "XXX",
    "expires_in": 3570,
    "issuer": "https://accounts.google.com",
    "issued_at": 1610010647
}
```

There is no service account `email` field!

Answer (score 2):

You have what you need in the documentation but I agree, it's not clear. It's named [function-to-function authentication](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#function-to-function).

In fact, because the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) is deployed on each computes element on Google Cloud, you can reuse this solution everywhere (or almost everywhere! You can't generate an `id_token` on Cloud Build, I [wrote an article and a workaround on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/service-account-credentials-api-a-solution-to-different-issues-dc7434037115))

This article provides also a great workaround for local testing (because you don't have metadata server on your computer!)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have updated the question with some follow up, kindly have a look.
Basically, I am already doing what you have mentioned in my current code but I am getting a `403`.

Comment: Do you use extra feature such as workload identity? Are you able to log the id_token generated before calling the Cloud Function and to use jwt.io website to extract the service account email contained in it? Like this, you will be able to check if it's the expected service account used, and checks its roles

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Basically when I decode the `id_token` it does not have the `email`. Decoding an `id_token` generated from `$ gcloud auth print-identity-token` shows extra fields that I don't see on the token from the metadata server.


I am going through your post on medium, regarding the service account identity API, can you please tell me if the following endpoint is correct?
https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/generateIdToken?name=projects/project-name/serviceAccounts/service-account-email